# In javavscript, what is the difference between: (function(){"use strict"}) (); and "use strict"?

Tags: javascript, function, mode, strict

What is the difference between:

```
(function () {'use strict';})();
```

and  `"use strict"`.

I don't understand when or why I would use one over the other?

I think that one declares the complete external JS document strict and the other makes a function strict.

My confusion comes when I see people enclose their complete external JavaScript in:

```
(function () {'use strict';})();
```

Why not just start the document with use `"use strict"`?

Lastly, I have tested an external JS doc using the same code.
One, I used `"use strict"` and it worked.

The other I enclosed the complete JS document with `(function () {'use strict';})();` and it did **not** work.

***Why?***

JavaScript is my first programming language and I am a little overwhelmed by its depth. I really appreciate your patience and professional guidance thank you for any help or direction you can offer me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: One applies to a single function, the other applies to every function in the file.  Maybe applying it to everything is undesired.

Answer (score 3):

If you

```
"use strict";
```

At the top of the file, the *entire file* (that is, all code in the file/script tag, including third-party libraries [thanks VLAZ for clarification]) is strict.

Placing it inside an IIFE:

```
(function() { "use strict"; })();
```

Means that only code inside the IIFE will be strict.

Comment: @VLAZ "use strict" at the top of a file only affects that file.  It doesn't affect other scopes.  It would affect every script that is concatenated into a single file, but wouldn't affect other script files.  ES2015 also introduced a module-level mode that affects every script in that module.

Comment: @Amy thanks. I have no idea where I picked that from, then - I re-checked the sources I thought I saw it in and didn't see it. Must have hallucinated it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
(function() { "use strict"; })()
```

is completely useless; it has no effect on anything.

At the beginning of a scope, like a function or a `<script>` block,

```
"use strict";
```

signals the interpreter that you want code interpreted in "strict" mode. If it's in a function that does nothing, it has no meaningful effect on anything. Of course, if the *actual* function you're talking about has more code than just the `"use strict";` statement, then it means that that function will be interpreted in "strict" mode.

Comment: I originally downvoted you because the comment about it being useless was not needed and didn't help answer the question.  I think the insinuation is putting the strict mode call at the top of a IIFE module that has code in it, but the OP excluded code for brevity.  You added more information and I removed the downvote.  I still think the OP means that there would be more code in the IIFE besides the strict call.

Comment: @zero298 well making assumptions about what the OP posted is a thing that I've learned not to do after 10 years on this site; it's impossible to know what's really going on. Maybe the OP meant there would be more code, but maybe not. What I posted as an answer involved the exact code from the question.

Comment: IMO, assumptions are particularly important to avoid with beginners.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help!  @pointy Love your Van Eyke Avitar !!